# How to use selectInput to return value of a key corresponding to a label

Tags: r, shiny

In the package `Shiny`, the syntax:

```
  selectInput(inputId = "event_choice",
               label = "Choose event",
              selected = NULL,
               choices = events
  )
```

Displays a box telling users to choose an event from a drop down box populated with entries from the vector `events`. The user choice is then referenced by `input$event_choice` on the server side.

Consider the following data frame `df`:

```
event_id    events
________    _________
139         Alex visited on 2016-01-01
140         Alex left on 2016-02-01
150         ...
```

with the vector `events = df$events`.

Using this descriptive vector obviously makes it easier for the user to navigate the drop down in `selectInput`. However, when doing further subsets or operations on data, it is more useful and concise to use the `event_id`.

What is the best way to map the selected input to the `event_id`? I know I can use standard matching algorithms in the `data.frame`, but was wondering whether there was anything better in the context of Shiny.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the `choice` argument

> **choices**    List of values to select from. If elements of the list are
>   named then that name rather than the value is displayed to the user.

So you can use a named list with names being `events` column and values being `event_id` column. As suggested by @alistaire in the comments below, an easy and straightforward way is

```
choices = setNames(df$event_id, df$event)
```

Comment: `setNames` makes this pretty straightforward: `choices = setNames(df$event_id, df$event)`