# In Shiny selectInput: to have many columns value et label with vertical align (and spaces not merged)

Tags: html, r, dataframe, shiny, whitespace

I would like to vertical align some text in my dataframe.

Therefore I would like kept more than one space in dataframe.

```
toto<-'A    B'
toto

df <- data.frame(name=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df[1,"name"]<-toto
df
```

but I get only one space at the end:

```
'A    B'
name
A B
```

(I have searched everywhere)

Comment: that code works fine. Try using the reprex package to post your code https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex

Comment: It's a reprex : I get one space and I would like keep the spaces, like my code copy-pasted here :) I don't understand your comment

Comment: It occures in Shiny but also in Jupyter. It's for a select input with value and label, but It's also a general question : why spaces are stripped in dataframe by default ? So this simple code.

Comment: R version 3.4.4

Comment: I see multiple spaces in the output.

Comment: spaces aren't stripped "by default" in data frames. You have not provided a true reproducible example. Anyone that runs the code in the first block gets the string with the spaces

Comment: When I print I get the spaces, when I `View(df)` spaces are removed.

Comment: try `toto <- gsub(" ","&nbsp;",toto)` before running your shiny code (and edit your post to reflect that this happens in your shiny app but not in interactive mode).

Comment: ah yes ?!. With `R -i` and RStudio I have the spaces, with Jupyter and Shiny I have only one space. So it's html issue oO. I look forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial goal was for `selectInput()`. I change a little the title.

Here is quickly the solution I've found.

I've not found a beautiful solution like `escape` of `DT::datatable(df,escape=1)`.

With

**ui.R**

font-family monospace for vertical align.

```
fluidRow(
  div(selectInput("outputmyselectlist",
      label=c("Filtre"),
      choices=NULL,
      width = '75%'
      )
  ,style='font-family: Consolas,monospace;')
)
```

**server.R**

```
updateSelectizeInput(session, "outputmyselectlist",
   server = TRUE, 
   choices = df,
   options = list(render = I(
   '{
       option: function(item, escape) {
         return "<div    data-value=\\""+ 
         escape(item.value)+
         "\\"   data-selectable=\\"\\" class=\\"option\\"   >" +
         (item.label.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;")) +
         "</div>"
       }
    }'))
)
```

with my dataframe like that:

```
df0<-data.frame(value=c("a","b"), label=c("AAA","BBB"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df<-df0 %>% mutate ( label=paste0(value,strrep(' ',14-nchar (value)),'|',label))
```

**Reproducible example :**

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", 
             HTML(".label_non_fixe_items_fixes .selectize-control {font-family: Consolas,monospace;})")),
  div(
    uiOutput("myselectinputUI"),
    class='label_non_fixe_items_fixes')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata.list <- reactive  ({
    (mtcars 
     %>% mutate (
       myid = row_number(), 
       myname = rownames(mtcars)
     ) %>% select (myid, myname,hp)
    )
  })


  output$myselectinputUI <- renderUI({
    res <-( mydata.list() 
            %>% transmute (value=myid, 
                           label= paste0(myid,
                                         strrep(' ',2-nchar (myid)),
                                         '|',myname,
                                         strrep(' ',20-nchar (myname)),
                                         '|',hp
                           )
            )
    )
    list_label_value = setNames(res$value, res$label)

    selectizeInput(
      inputId="myselectinputUI",
      label= "my select input",
      choices = list_label_value,
      options = list(
        render = I(
          '{
                       option: function(item, escape) {
                           return "<div    data-value=\\""+
                           escape(item.value)+
                           "\\" data-selectable=\\"\\" class=\\"option\\" >" +
                           (item.label.replace(/ /g, "&nbsp;")) +
                           "</div>"
                       }
                      }'
        )
      )
    )
  })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Links :

- https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html
- [In Shiny can a data frame be used as choices in selectizeInput?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51000637/10489562) (as a reminder about label and value in the dataframe of a `selectInput`).
- [How to use selectInput to return value of a key corresponding to a label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001314/how-to-use-selectinput-to-return-value-of-a-key-corresponding-to-a-label) with `choices = setNames(df$label, df$value)` if the form of data generates an unwanted `optgroup`. (An `isolate()` on a `reactive()` breaks a little the form of the data).